# How do I make a UIImage being drawn with drawInRect using a UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, drawrect

I have a custom `UIView` I'm doing drawing in, and in the `drawRect` function I'm creating a circle shape (with a hollow center, so picture a donut) as a `UIBezierPath`.

I then want to use this `UIBezierPath`/circle shape as the mask for when I draw my `UIImage` with `drawInRect`. So in the end I'll have a donut shape with an image background.

I create the circle/`UIBezierPath` as follows:

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
let progress = CGFloat(1.0)
let diameter = CGFloat(32.0)

let gapExpression: CGFloat = diameter * CGFloat(M_PI)
let dashExpression: CGFloat = progress * diameter * CGFloat(M_PI)

CGContextSaveGState(context)
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 19, 19)
CGContextRotateCTM(context, -270 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180)

var circlePath = UIBezierPath()
circlePath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(-16, 0))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, -16), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(-16, -8.84), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(-8.84, -16))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(16, 0), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(8.84, -16), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(16, -8.84))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 16), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(16, 8.84), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(8.84, 16))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(-16, 0), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(-8.84, 16), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(-16, 8.84))
circlePath.closePath()
circlePath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;

UIColor.grayColor().setStroke()
circlePath.lineWidth = 5
CGContextSaveGState(context)
CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, [dashExpression, gapExpression], 2)
circlePath.stroke()
CGContextRestoreGState(context)
```

Which if I just have that in my `drawRect` it outputs a circle/donut shape.

However I also have a `UIImage`:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "test-shape")
```

That I draw using `drawInRect`, but I want the image to be masked by the `UIBezierPath` above.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Save the context, add a clip, set the scale, and draw the image.

This should be close:

```
circlePath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;      // existing

// add these lines
CGContextSaveGState(context)
circlePath.addClip()
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1)
CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, test-shape.size.width, test-shape.size.height), test-shape.CGImage)
CGContextRestoreGState(context)

UIColor.grayColor().setStroke()                 //existing
```

Edit to add alternative: This draws a donut and fills it with the image. But the line dash is not probably going to have the effect you need. Perhaps this can help in some way.

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

let testshape = UIImage(named: "testshape.png")!

var circlePath = UIBezierPath()
circlePath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(9.5, 2.5))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(6.1, 3.38), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(8.27, 2.5), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(7.11, 2.82))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(2.5, 9.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(3.95, 4.58), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(2.5, 6.87))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(9.5, 16.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(2.5, 13.37), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(5.63, 16.5))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(16.5, 9.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(13.37, 16.5), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(16.5, 13.37))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(9.5, 2.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(16.5, 5.63), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(13.37, 2.5))
circlePath.closePath()
circlePath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(19, 9.5))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(9.5, 19), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(19, 14.75), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(14.75, 19))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 9.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(4.25, 19), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(-0, 14.75))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(3.88, 1.84), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(0, 6.36), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(1.53, 3.57))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(9.5, 0), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(5.45, 0.68), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(7.4, 0))
circlePath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(19, 9.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(14.75, 0), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(19, 4.25))
circlePath.closePath()
circlePath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;

CGContextSaveGState(context)
circlePath.addClip()
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1)
CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, testshape.size.width, testshape.size.height), testshape.CGImage)
CGContextRestoreGState(context)
```

[image: donut]

If you just want a half circle, here is a quick example of how to draw that. Just use that as the mask. Rotate as needed.

```
let color = UIColor(red: 0.742, green: 0.000, blue: 1.000, alpha: 1.000)

var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(56, 45))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(31, 70), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(56, 58.81), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(44.81, 70))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(26, 65), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(28.24, 70), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(26, 67.76))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(31, 60), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(26, 62.24), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(28.24, 60))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(46, 45), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(39.28, 60), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(46, 53.28))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(31, 30), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(46, 36.72), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(39.28, 30))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(26, 25), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(28.24, 30), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(26, 27.76))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(29.45, 20.24), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(26, 22.78), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(27.45, 20.9))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(31, 20), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(29.94, 20.09), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(30.46, 20))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(56, 45), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(44.81, 20), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(56, 31.19))
bezierPath.closePath()
color.setFill()
bezierPath.fill()
```

[image: half circle with rounded ends]

Comment: I did this, and the result ended up with the gray circular border and the image on the inside of the circle (the image is just a purple square). Here's what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/bMnnf8p.png, and I'm looking for this: http://i.imgur.com/SEDdfNT.png where the purple is masked by the donut shape.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to do. Your trying to use the LINE as the mask. I don't think you can do that. You probably need to draw a circle within a circle and use the image as the fill. Let me update answer...

Comment: Well, sorry. I played around with it, and could get the purple to properly fill the shape, but what you're doing with the dashes is obviously not going to work now. I'll add it to the answer above, maybe it will be useful.

Comment: That is a big help, thank you! I'm curious though, if I just want donut shaped circle (this is for a progress indicator) to use as a mask, am I overcomplicating it? Is there an easier way to be doing this? I don't need to be doing all the things with dashes, if I can make the stroke not go all the way around (so it's a half circle) that works fine! I just can't help but think I'm overcomplicating this. :/ (New to Core Graphics.)

Comment: Perhaps draw your half-circle shape, then rotate it as needed?

Comment: How does one draw a half-circle shape exactly? That's what I was trying to replicate with the dashes.

Comment: Is it possible to do that while still being able to set the line cap style to round? (kCGLineCapRound)

Comment: Well, it's a shape, not a line. But yeah, you can certainly draw it with rounded ends that "look" like cap style round. And, I'm just filling it with a solid color, but you can still use an image if you need to.

Comment: You might even look at this answer for something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31619116/600753